# comparing two dissimilar vectors of same length in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, comparison

I have two matrix A and B. A is a array of length 1000X1 consisting of 0's and 1's and B is also of the same size. Now B is the output of a function that performs a sweep operation taking A as input. Sweep is nothing but addition of zeros in the place of 1 in A. so values of B is similar to A except some of the 1's are replaced by 0's. Now my task is to fill those 0 values in B which was replaced after sweep operation by random binary values.I have done this with help of a user form this awesome website. And the code for the same is here

```
idx=strfind(B,[0 0 0 0]);
n=dec2bin(randi([0 15],[numel(idx) 1]),4) - '0';
idx=bsxfun(@plus, idx', (0:3));
xx = B;
xx(idx(:)) = n(:);
```

Now this function will also replace the zeros which was already present in A. I want to replace only those zeros which were changed from 1's to 0's and not those 0's which were already zeros in A. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
function modifiedB=modifyB(A,B)
  idx=(A~=B); %% or idx=((A==1)&(B==0)); %% find the indices where B changed
  B(idx)=(rand(nnz(idx),1)>0.5); %% replace at those indices by random numbers
  modifiedB=B;
end
```

Comment: Where should i add this code in the above function!! By the way thank you very much for replying!!

Comment: you should do that right after computing "B=sweep(A);" The code above will replace the changed coordinate of B by random binary numbers.

Comment: So i shouldn't use the code that i posted above ? will these two lines of yours do the magic? after sweep operation, random zeros will appear in B and i just want those zeros to be replaced by random binary values and not the one which was already zero!! Could you please tell me how i could add this code of yours in function that would take A and B as input and will give a modified version of B as output!! thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: And one more thing oli, as i can see from the second line of your code you replace those indices with random values , but are they binary?

Comment: "(rand(nnz(idx),1)>0.5)": This line generates random numbers between 0 and 1, and then all the numbers above 0.5 are set to 1, and the numbers below 0.5 are set to 0.

Comment: Hi oli, thank you very much, but i have a small question what if i want to find four consecutive zeros in B after sweep is performed and want to change those four zeros to random binary values from 1-15? the four consequitve zeros should not include those zeros which were already present in A. The four consequitve 0 should be the zeros that are changed after the sweep operation. Is it possible to do so? Any help would be very much appreciated!